# Highcharts Solid Gauge With PHP Data

Tags: php, mysql, json, highcharts, gauge

- Solid Gauge is to be displayed for each humidity value that I call from MySql.
  I don't know what else to attempt now that I've been struggling for days.
  It doesn't work in any way,
  can you please try and help me with my project?

The value appears to be pulled from php in the image I shared; however, I guess I overlooked something and the graphic is unable to detect this number.

**HTML**

```
<?php
include("hum.php");

?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Highcharts Tutorial</title>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
      <script src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>    
      <script src = "https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.highcharts.com/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>
   </head>       
   <body>
      <div style = "width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
         <div id = "container-speed" style = "width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left">
         </div>             
      </div>  
      <script language = "JavaScript">
         $(function () { 
var gaugeOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge'
    },
    title: null,
    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '85%'],
        size: '100%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickPixelInterval: 400,
        tickWidth: 0,
        title: {
            y: -70
        },
        labels: {
            y: 16
        }
    },   
   plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                y: 5,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
    }
};   
// The speed gauge
$('#container-speed').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 200,
        title: {
            text: 'Speed'
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]
}));
// Bring life to the dials
setInterval(function () {
    point = $('#container-speed').highcharts().series[0].points[0];  
                humidity;
                $.getJSON("hum.php", function(data) {
                point.update(parseFloat(humidity));
            });
            }, 2000);
});
      </script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
$mysqli= new mysqli('localhost', 'root','','sensorsdata');
$sql = '
SELECT humidity, 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT_WS(" ", date, time)) AS datetime 
FROM allv1
ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT 1
';
$result_4 = $mysqli->query($sql);
while($row_4 = $result_4->fetch_assoc()) {
  echo $row_4['humidity'];
}
?>
```

[For the time being, this is how it appears on the screen:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Es6Hc.png)

[My php table is like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfs8h.png)

if I solve this, I will chart in other values.

**EDİT**

The tries were successful. ** ajax is what got me to the answer...

Just adapt the setInterval part like this.

```
setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
    url: "hum.php",
    data: 'gauge1',
    type:'get',
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false, 
    success: function(data){
        var humidity = $.parseJSON(data);
                var chart = $('#container-speed').highcharts();
                chart.series[0].points[0].update(humidity);        
    }
});
}, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `point = $('#container-speed').highcharts().series[0].points[0];` is undefined because the initial data is an empty array - so no point has been rendered. Try to set some initial dummy data, for example:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Speed',
    data: [1],
    dataLabels: {
        format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
            ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
               '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
    },
    tooltip: {
        valueSuffix: ' km/h'
    }
}]
```

Comment: Wedzel I gave it a shot. Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: @melikeköse does the point refer to the `point` object? What is the value of the `humidity`? Do you have any errors on the console? Are you able to reproduce your issue on the some online editor with the sample data?

Comment: What you said was always due to my confusion, but it seems to have worked now. without the need to reload the page. @SebastianWedzel

Comment: @melikeköse you mean that the problem is solved?

Comment: I made a few changes above. *-*  now i'm trying to do it for temperature as well @SebastianWedzel

Comment: @melikeköse - I see, in case of any issues - please reproduce your issue with the sample data on some online editor

Comment: alright thank you